# login with social.js failed to get the Request Token

Tags: javascript, authentication, linkedin-api, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I am using social.js (https://gist.github.com/rampicos/4320296) to authenticate user in my Appcelerator mobile app.
I am however getting the error:

```
[ERROR]    :  Social.js: FAILED to getRequestToken!
[ERROR]    :oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_consumer_key&oauth_problem=parameter_absent
[ERROR] :  2015-10-02 22:15:06.628 Example[78076:253765] Simulator user has requested new graphics quality: 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LinkedIn developer web site announced server maintenance on October 2nd.
Is it related to your problem?

[LinkedIn Developer Website](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/)